# The page isn’t redirecting properly backoffice magento fresh installation Version 2.1.16

Tags: magento2

Fresh installation of magento 2.1.16, throwing error admin url

This page isn’t working

XXX.XXX.com redirected you too many times.

Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 1):

I was having underscore in domain name example local.magento2_1.com

I replaced underscore with dash (-) it fixed the issue

changed local.magento2_1.com  to local.magento2-1.com

Comment: Strange thing ...